# php sort only the records from the pagination page

Tags: php, sorting, pagination

I have a pagination, with limit 10 for example. If I'm on page 2 and click on sort, I'd like to sort just the records shown on the current pagination page; when I come back to page 1 I'd like the records to be sorted as they were before I sorted the 2nd page. Any tips how this can be achieved?

Maybe something like this:

```
if ($page == 1){ 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $orderby $sort LIMIT $start, $perpage");
} else {}
```

But for the ELSE I don't know how to limit just the 10 records from the current page.

Comment: @Prasanth Bendra: I added some code in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing the current pages records in a javascript array and sorting it on the client?

Comment: you should post it as a comment not an answer.

Comment: and your comment is constructive how?

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you click next or previous page or while sorting, pass sort details as well as page details through url and get those in page and use those in your query .

Answer (score 0):

No Mysql tagged here, so in php you could try

`$arr` contains all data from users-table

```
// on every page you slice the original array $page_num = 2, $amount_of_items_per_page = 10
$page_arr = array_slice($arr, $page_num*$amout_of_items_per_page, $amout_of_items_per_page);
```

Then if you want to sort somehow, you have to sort $page_arr.

```
sort ($page_arr); 
ksort($page_arr);
```